# aws ec2 createInstance policy implementation

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, createinstance

I have to assign a policy on a particular user, so that he could be able to create only particular type of ec2 instance, in a particular region. Say a developer x could be able to perform all action in us -east region's ec2 service on high memory instance type only. He should not be able to create or perform action on any other instance type.

Please let me know if there is a way to assign such policy.
Thanks in advance.

Thanks & Regards
Manu Misra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not - policies for ec2 are only at the action level. You can't restrict them to particular instances or instance types. I don't even think you could restrict them to a single region.

Comment: Frederick Cheung: Thank you for your reply. So is there any alternate way of restricting my developers to a particular instance type or region atleast?